# Regex for matching any content between curly brackets, except for single-digit numbers?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a very specific regex, one that matches to all content between { } EXCEPT single-digit numbers. So, here are a few examples:

- {a} - match
- {aB} - match
- {1} - NO MATCH
- {1g} - match
- {55-5} - match
- {46512} - match
- {5} - NO MATCH
- {4E-2D} - match
- {A4} - match
- {ASD 5D} - match

So far, the thing that works correctly for me is the match for beginning opening curly bracket `(?<=\{)` and closing at the end `(?=\})`, but have been unsuccessful with the expression in between. Would really appreciate some ideas.

Comment: This question seems really clear with what has been tried and what the expected matches are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 parts of the pattern. To match what is in between except for when there is a single digit:

```
 (?<={)(?!\d})[^{}]+(?=})
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<={)` Assert `{` to the left
- `(?!\d})` Assert not `\d}` to the right
- `[^{}]+` Match any char except `{` or `}`
- `(?=})` Assert `}` at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pfuIbi/1)

Comment: Thanks alot, really fast answer and works like a charm